# OOPHP calling a function within a function

Tags: php, mysql, sql, flash-builder

OK so I am using OOPHP to communicate between Flash Builder and MYSQL both functions work but when i call one of the functions within the other it throws an error

ERROR: Server error MySQL Error - 2014
I have search the Internet and cant find any suitable answers.

Is it because the first function has a lock on the MYSQL database and so the second cant access the database?

The reason i have this problem is in one Table i have the clients country as initials and i have created a second table with what the initials stand for i.e. UK = United Kingdom, i did this as at the time i guess i thought this would be good database practice to save space if the client table went to many records.

So now i am calling a function that gives me a particular client but within that call i wanted to call the second function to change the country initials into the correct country string.

FIRST FUNCTION

```
public function getClients($item) {

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection, "SELECT timestamp, id, fname, lname, dateofbirth, monthofbirth, yearofbirth,
    town, country, sex, rate, comments from $this->tablename WHERE (id = $item)");  
    $this->throwExceptionOnError();

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $this->throwExceptionOnError();

    $rows = array();

    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $row->timestamp, $row->ID, $row->fname, $row->lname, $row->dateofbirth, $row->monthofbirth, 
    $row->yearofbirth, $row->sex, $row->country, $row->town, $row->rate, $row->comments);

    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
      $row->fname = ucfirst(substr($row->fname,0,1));
      $row->lname = ucfirst($row->lname);
      $row->town = ucfirst($row->town);
      $row->comments = strip_tags($row->comments);
      $row->lname = (($row->fname) . " " . ($row->lname));
      $row->country = $this->getCountry($row->country);
      $row->yearofbirth = GetAge($row->dateofbirth. '-' .$row->monthofbirth. '-' .$row->yearofbirth);
      $row->Pic_loc = "";
      $row->Pic_loc= "SLAGSIMAGES/".($row->ID)."/image01.jpg";
      $row->timestamp = new DateTime($row->timestamp);
      $rows[] = $row;
      $row = new stdClass();
      mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $row->timestamp, $row->id,$row->fname,$row->lname,$row->sex,$row->country,$row->town,$row->dateofbirth,
      $row->monthofbirth,$row->yearofbirth, $row->rate, $row->comments);
    }


    mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);
    mysqli_close($this->connection);



    return $rows;
}
```

And this is the second function that is called by the first

```
public function getCountry($countrycode) {

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection, "SELECT country FROM countrycodes where CountryCodes ='$countrycode'");       
    $this->throwExceptionOnError();

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $this->throwExceptionOnError();

    $rows = array();

    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $row->country);

    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
      $rows[] = $row;
      $row = new stdClass();
      mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $row->country);
    }

    mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);
    mysqli_close($this->connection);

    return $rows;
}
```

This is the piece of code in the first function that is throwing the error
 `$row->country = $this->getCountry($row->country);`

Sorry if code is a little confusing but thanks in advance for any correct answer or info to tell my brain why it can't be done.

Comment: "coz" isn't a word, please don't use chat speak in your SO posts.

Comment: Yes it's because you have a connection open/locked with the first SQL.  Perhaps you can `JOIN` the SQL into one lookup, or do one fetch/close then do the other fetch.

Comment: thanks Rudu, This is what i was thinking too i just needed someone to confirm so i could sit there to puzzle through the join :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"So now I am calling a function that gives me a particular client but within that call I wanted to call the second function to change the country initials into the correct country string"

Why not just join to the other SQL table in the first function, get the data you need and not have to call a second function?

Comment: I think i was going wrong because i was trying to incorporate what i had rather than sit their and use my brain to create a join, got there in the end. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php
```

> Note:
>
> When using mysqli_stmt_execute(), the mysqli_stmt_fetch() function
>   must be used to fetch the data prior to performing any additional
>   queries.

like all the mysql stuff you can do one query at a time
the other way to go around this is to work with pool of connections
and do something like

```
$link = (find_first_available_connection_from_pool) (should return locked link)
query($link..)
release($link) [unlock]
```